# css flipped block interaction with non flipped, only webkit specific

Tags: css, webkit, flip

okey, simple css flip

```
.container  
  .flipper.A
     .front  
     .back
  .flipper.B
     .front
     .back
```

it's important for me, that `.front` and `.back` both have negative `top` and `left` absolute position
and `.flipper` dimensions is `0x0`

when `flipper A` is rotatedY 180deg, so `.back` is visible, it incorrectly interacts with other `.flippers` if their positions intersect. For example, i click on links in flipper B, but can't click on links in flipper A, if A is over B

working example is here http://jsfiddle.net/attenzione/g2at2/ - you almost can click on test 1, instead click on test 3

such situation only appear on webkit browser

any help with it? is this webkit bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bring the div that you want to be in front towards the front (in 3d space)

CSS

```
div.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(-1px);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

the translateZ moves it towards you

[corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/g2at2/2/)

Comment: thanx a lot! is this webkit bug or my issue? because ff works fine
btw, your fiddle is not corrected, maybe missed to save? but got your answer without it

Comment: I think that there is a small bug of webkit in the base of that. In webkit, when you rotate something 180deg in the x or y axis, the rotation is off a little bit. That makes that the rotated element can be "down" also a little bit. I am guessing that, but I believe that this is in the origin of several strange behaviours of this kind. At least in this aspect, ff works way better. And you are right, forgot to save my edits ...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why your inner .block has absolute positioning? This is what is causing the issue. If you must use absolute positioning on the inner block then there are two ways round this.

You could overflow hidden the outer element (.flipper)
Or you could add pointer-events:none on the unflipped element, bear in mind this only works back to IE9

You should really try not to use absolute positioning though as it isn't needed.

Comment: sorry, .block really need to be absolute positioned with negative top and left